# Force flash player quality low on IE10 or imacros browser

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am trying to put the flash player quality low in imacros browser, but I get a parsing error. Flash consumes a lot of CPU in my laptop, with low quality the performance will be supposedly excellent.

```
URL GOTO=javascript:for (var objs = document.embeds, i = objs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    objs[i].setAttribute('quality', 'low');
    with (objs[i].parentNode) appendChild(removeChild(objs[i]));
}

for (objs = document.getElementsByTagName('object'), i = objs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (var c = objs[i].childNodes, j = c.length - 1, set = false; j >= 0; j--) {
        if ((c[j].tagName == 'PARAM') && (c[j].getAttribute('name') == 'quality')) { c[j].setAttribute('value', 'low'); set = true; break; }
    }
    if (!set) with (objs[i].appendChild(document.createElement('param'))) setAttribute('name', 'quality'), setAttribute('value', 'low');

    with (objs[i].parentNode) appendChild(removeChild(objs[i]));
}
```

Comment: i get Error -1100: Can not parse macro line:     objs[i].setAttribute('quality', 'low');